# How to do a function for every folder containing certain file?

Tags: applescript

I'm having a bit of trouble with AppleScript...

**Long story short - what I'm trying to do is to do a function for every folder of *parrentFolder* containing *someFile*.**

Basicaly, I have a complex folder structure with multiple folders ending up with a couple of files, within which (sometimes) there's a 'Preview.png' file. Now what I'm trying to do is to run a function that will go over each and every folder and whenever it finds 'Preview.png' within a folder it should store folder's path after which I can run a function to change the icon of that folder to a 'Preview.png' image. And it should loop over all of the folders in the main folder.

Anyone able to give me a hand?

Thanks,
Marko

Comment: I have a working function that sets image as icon of a folder, so that's good. And I know how to have a prompt for a start folder. Basically it's the loop part I'm stuck with.

I've tried adding variable for `startFolder` as `/some-folder` and then another `everyFolder`  as  `every folder of  startFolder`, after which I tried to run `if exists everyFolder & 'Preview.png' as POSIX file...` - but that didn't work, as it just checks the first 'layer' of folders.

What I think I need is something that works like 'forEach' in JS - where I would do a function for each folder.

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Comment: Every Finder object (file/folder) had a property container. That's the parent folder, or you can do is with `do shell script` and use the `../` to get the parent folder of any folder/file.